# JSONObject has nested key

Tags: java, json, org.json

I want to read a json configuration file and execute code if a specific value exists.

```
{
    "database": {
        "port": 3306
    }
}
```

I use [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) from maven central.

```
if (jsonObject.has("database.port")) {
    // Get content of "database.port" and call logic
}
```

By default, database.port won't get recognized as a nested path. How can i tell org.json that this is a nested path?

```
if (jsonObject.has("database") && jsonObject.getJSONObject("database").has("port")
```

This works just fine, but i have more nested values it gets quite messy.

Is there a better way to get the content instead of writing the path two times (1x for JSONObject#has(...) and 1x for JSONObject#getInt(...))

Comment: JSONObject d=jsonObject.get("database"); String port=d.getString("port");

Comment: @rupps then i have to use `if (jsonObject.has("database") && jsonObject.getJSONObject("database").has("port"))` which is quite inconvenient (especially if i have more nested values).

Comment: the json library you are using is the most basic, and does not include nethods for nested paths.

Comment: You could use https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rupps said, org.json doesn't support nested paths. I upgraded to gson which supports much more advanced parsing. [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) looks nice but it seems a bit overkill for my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, org.json does not support nested parsing. But you can try to convert JSON to bean, it will be much easier